# Does MinGW-w64 support std::thread out of the box when using the Win32 threading model?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, mingw-w64

I opted for the Win32 threading model when installing the MinGW-w64 toolchain, after reading that it provides better performance than the POSIX counterpart. I am not qualified for benchmarking this claim myself, but [here's a source](https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW-64-bit#GCC_Threading_model_.28posix_vs_win32.29).

At first I thought this option would only affect the inner workings of the GCC runtime, while not preventing me from using C++11 threads in my code, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30390278/3258851) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29947302/meaning-of-options-in-mingw-w64-installer#comment48868740_30178674) by fellow user *[rubenvb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256138/rubenvb)*.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. `std::thread` support appears to be non-existent in this MinGW-w64 installation.

I'm invoking *g++* from the command line with no options other than `-std=c++11`.

At this point I'm not sure if:

- *rubenvb* was mistaken, and it's actually necessary to install MinGW-w64 under the POSIX threading model in order to compile my code which depends on the C++11 `thread` library, or;
- I completely misunderstood it all, or;
- `std::thread` is actually supported in my scenario, it's just not intuitive.

I reinforce the "out of the box" part in the title. There exists a library called [mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads), as presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27490675/3258851). However, as a third-party option, it is not relevant to this question.

So, as of today (May 2016), does MinGW-w64 nativelly support `std::thread` depending code, when installed with the Win32 internal threading model?

Comment: installing mingw-std-threads as you linked to, works and takes about 30 seconds

Comment: @M.M ... Thanks for the suggestion, I did that already. This question is mainly for the sake of curiosity/canonicity, however. Information seem to diverge between different sources.

Comment: Neither my answer nor my comment are wrong. They were written in a time where the mingw-std-threads library wasn't available (or at least I wasn't aware of it). GCC with its internal threading model set to win32 does not support C++11 threading functionality, period. My answer you linked says exactly this. My comment on the other hand doesn't talk about C++11 thread support. Instead, it deals with calling pthreads or win32 thread related functions with GCC built with win32/posix as its internal threading model, which all works as one would expect. These are two very different topics.

Comment: Hi @rubenvb, thank you for your input. It seems then that Point 2 - "I completely misunderstood it all" - is the case. I didn't pay proper attention to the fact that you refer to the term "API".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To use the MinGW-w64 with Win32 native threads you can install the [mingw-std-threads](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads) headers.

As described on that page, this is because MinGW-w64 is a port of GCC, but GCC does not include any native thread support. Instead GCC installations typically implement threading via either gthreads or pthreads as a part of glibc.   MinGW-w64 does not include a port of glibc. (Instead it uses a combination of the MSVC runtime, plus its own code to fill in holes).

Also as described on that page, recent versions of MinGW-w64 do include a Win32 port of pthreads ("winpthreads"), which explains why you can have threads work "out of the box" by selecting the "pthread" model from the MinGW-w64 installer.