# How to compile C++ std::thread code with MinGW?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, mingw

I would like to compile my c++11 project (recently moved to c++11) with MinGW. And I have compiling errors about c++11 code like "std::thread not found".

I used the last MinGW with gcc 5.3.0 (December 2015). A the end, I would like only to compile this example before to compile my big project :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

void foo()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

void bar()
{
    // simulate expensive operation
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "starting first helper...\n";
    std::thread helper1(foo);

    std::cout << "starting second helper...\n";
    std::thread helper2(bar);

    std::cout << "waiting for helpers to finish..." << std::endl;
    helper1.join();
    helper2.join();

    std::cout << "done!\n";
}
```

(source : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

I tried "g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp" and "g++ main.cpp -std=c++0x" but I have always those following errors :

```
main.cpp: In function 'void foo()':
main.cpp:8:10: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
          ^
main.cpp: In function 'void bar()':
main.cpp:14:10: error: 'std::this_thread' has not been declared
     std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
          ^
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:20:5: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
     std::thread helper1(foo);
     ^
main.cpp:23:5: error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
     std::thread helper2(bar);
     ^
main.cpp:26:5: error: 'helper1' was not declared in this scope
     helper1.join();
     ^
main.cpp:27:5: error: 'helper2' was not declared in this scope
     helper2.join();
     ^
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358856/does-mingw-w64-support-stdthread-out-of-the-box-when-using-the-win32-threading , mingw (at least older versions) doesn't support std::thread out of the box

Answer (score 2):

MinGW mostly does not have a port of glibc which supports pthreading or gthreading like in GCC.

For solving this, the  first solution can be installing [library of thread headers](https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads).
The other solution can be working with GCC compiler.