# C++ multithreading errors

Tags: c++

I have been starting to try and learn how to utilize multithreading in c++, but the `#include<thread>` causes issues with the thread type being not declared in the scope. `error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope`. I have been doing research, and I have come across a lot of answers regarding how to solve this issue. Im presently at the understanding that my compiler, MinGW, doesn't support thread effectively, but I am not sure what to do with that information.

Any guidance on this matter is appreciated.

Also, I think this may be helpful. If I run `gcc -v` on my command line, I get this output:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)
```

edit: I've seen this webpage, https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads, as a potential solution, but I don't think this works for me. Unless somehow I am putting the mingw-thread.h in the wrong folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does MinGW-w64 support std::thread out of the box when using the Win32 threading model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358856/does-mingw-w64-support-stdthread-out-of-the-box-when-using-the-win32-threading)

Comment: Post your actual code, otherwise known as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I suspect it's something subtle and easy in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is you did not tell the compiler using c++11 features. 'thread' is belonged to c++11 features, let try adding `-std=c++11` into CXXFLAGS or CPPFLAGS and see if it resolves your problem

Comment: You mean to compile a program with "g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp"? Because no that doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Here is problem:
- `thread` is belong to name space `std`, so without name space `std` it will lead to your error.
- If you declare your variable as `std:thread` and compiler gives error as `thread` is not member of `std`, it cause of with thread model win32, g++ is lack of gthread library, so it cannot manipulate class `std::thread`. So solution is:
*Install gthread library with mingw, add include gthread header above `#include <thread>`
*Using substitute solution as you found above
*Re-install and using posix thread model

Answer (score 0):

My psychic powers suggest your forgot the `std::` namespace attribute.  That would explain why `thread` is undefined, even with `#include <thread>`.  The other answer about `-std=c++11` is also steering you into the right direction.  And don't forget the `-pthread` compiler/linker option.

```
$ cat foo.cpp
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

void threadfunc()
{
   std::cout << "Hello from the worker thread" << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
   std::thread t(threadfunc);
   t.join();
   return 0;
}

$ g++ foo.cpp -std=c++11 -o foo -pthread
$ ./foo
Hello from the worker thread
```

Comment: Using that file in addition to the compilation command you suggested still does not help. The error with that is "error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'", and also there's an obvious "t was not declared in this scope", but yeah. I've tried that and no luck

Comment: You're running `g++`  as your compiler command line and not `gcc`, right?  And your source file extension is `.cpp` instead of something else?

Comment: Yes exactly. I am using Visual studio codes built-in terminal. I cd to the directory containing my Testing.cpp which currently is a copy of your file from above. In the terminal command line, I run "g++ Testing.cpp -std=c++11 -o testing -pthread" and get the two errors.