# Using std::thread in AppVeyor with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, stdthread, appveyor

I'm trying to use AppVeyor for a C++ program made using Qt.
My appveyor.yml only do the 3 following things:

```
    - cd Project
    - qmake Project.pro
    - mingw32-make
```

But when AppVeyor is trying to compile my project it tells me

```
    error: 'thread' is not a member of 'std'
```

I'm sure the problem isn't from my code because it works on my computer or when using Travis CI

I'm also putting a link to the CI just in case:
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Xwilarg/programmanager/builds/23421335

Would someone please know how I can use std::thread in AppVeyor ?

Comment: Possible duplicate?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358856/does-mingw-w64-support-stdthread-out-of-the-box-when-using-the-win32-threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer of my question.

As Shloim said, I had to use https://github.com/meganz/mingw-std-threads

Then my CI wasn't able to find GetNativeSystemInfo so I had to add -D _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 in the compile flags

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've included `<thread>`, so the next guess would be that `std::thread` is part of c++11. You need to enable c++11 in your project.

Comment: I don't have any problem using things like unique_ptr so I think that C++11 already is enabled for the project