# C++ Multithreading with MinGW

Tags: c++, multithreading, g++, mingw

I would like to experiment with multithreading with c++. I am using the MinGW g++ compiler (version 8.2.0) on Windows 10. When I try to use the builtin thread library with c++ using the code I got directly from a website, I get the error:

> main.cpp:34:5: error: 'thread' was not declared in this scope
>        thread th1(foo, 3);
>        ^~~~~~ main.cpp:34:5: note: 'std::thread' is defined in header ''; did you forget to '#include '? main.cpp:5:1:
>   +#include   using namespace std; main.cpp:34:5:
>        thread th1(foo, 3);
>        ^~~~~~ main.cpp:38:11: error: expected ';' before 'th2'
>        thread th2(thread_obj(), 3);
>              ^~~~
>              ; main.cpp:49:11: error: expected ';' before 'th3'
>        thread th3(f, 3);
>              ^~~~
>              ; main.cpp:53:5: error: 'th1' was not declared in this scope
>        th1.join();
>        ^~~ main.cpp:56:5: error: 'th2' was not declared in this scope
>        th2.join();
>        ^~~ main.cpp:59:5: error: 'th3' was not declared in this scope
>        th3.join();
>        ^~~

Is this an issue with my specific to my compiler, or does MinGW simply not allow for the standard threading library? If not, what is a good library to use is substitute?

Comment: I did add #include <thread> it still fails, with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either:

- Choose the "pthreads" option when [installing mingw-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php/download/mingw-builds), or
- Choose the "Win32 threads" option when installing mingw-w64, and install an additional header file pack.

Another good option is to [install via MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2) which always gives you the latest build with a suitable configuration. (pthreads in this case).

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358856/does-mingw-w64-support-stdthread-out-of-the-box-when-using-the-win32-threading) for more info if you intend to not go via MSYS2.

Answer (score 0):

When you download mingw, there is a win32 version and a POSIX version. Get the POSIX and it will come with the std::thread implementation.